# Make Random img Visible in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm currently trying to show a random image. I don't know why it's not working. Please help.

Part of my html:

```
    <h2>
Roll Dice!
</h2>
<input type="button" onClick="rollDice()" value="Roll Dice!" />
<p></p>
<img src="images/one.png" class="dice" id="one"/>
<img src="images/two.png" class="dice" id="two"/>
<img src="images/three.png" class="dice" id="three"/>
<img src="images/four.png" class="dice" id="four"/>
<img src="images/five.png" class="dice" id="five"/>
<img src="images/six.png" class="dice" id="six"/>
```

Part of my js:

```
function getRandomNumber(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}



    function rollDice ()
    {
    var dicenum = getRandomNumber(1,6);
    if(dicenum === 1) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('one').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else if(dicenum === 2) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('two').style.visibility = "visible";


     }
    else if(dicenum === 3) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('three').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else if(dicenum === 4) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('four').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else if(dicenum === 5) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('five').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else if(dicenum === 6) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('six').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    }
```

Part of my CSS:

```
*
{
font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
.dice
{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Entire repo on GitHub: https://github.com/ThatRandomPerson/random-number-thing/
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make function for loop images:

```
function hideImages(images){
   for(var i = 0;i < images.length;i++){
        images[i].style.display = 'none';
   } 
}
```

Change:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById('one').style.visibility = "visible";
```

To in any condition:

```
hideImages(document.getElementByTagName('img'));
document.getElementById('one').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: How come (mim,max) work no matter what the variable is in the other functions?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection (a NodeList). You cannot apply style changes to the entire list, you will have to loop through them.

If you only want to effect one of these elements you could use `getElementsByTagName("img")[0]` to select the first image.

Using `getElementsByClassName` is better as there may be other images on the page.

Example looping:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("dice");
for (var i=0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    // do stuff with imgs[i]
}
```

Comment: So I would have to do it individually? Could I just do it with the IDs then?

Comment: You could do it with ids, although better would be to use their class-name and `getElementsByClassName` which is supported in most modern browsers. Loop through them, make them all invisible, then unhide the one (by id) that you want visible.

Comment: Does that mean I could replace getElementsByTagName with getElementsByClassName and not do it individually or still do it with the [x] at the end?

Comment: I would prefer to use the class-name, as the page is likely to have other images on it. Either way, you have to loop through them - doing it individually by id will create very messy code.

Comment: How would I loop it? Could you give an example?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.